# difference between TreeSets based on their interface

Tags: java, collections

Is there any difference between the two TreeSets ?:

```
Set<String> s = new TreeSet<String>();
SortedSet<String> s = new TreeSet<String>();
```

Comment: The second one won't compile.

Comment: Don't confuse static/compile time and dynamic/runtime types.

Comment: You're essentially asking about the difference between a variable's type and its referred to object's type.

Comment: @bluesony I might vote to reopen if you edit your Question for clarity and add some explanation. Your use of the variable named `s` in both lines of code creates some ambiguity about your intentions. Are you confused about re-using/recycling a variable’s name? Or are you confused about assigning a concrete class `TreeSet` to either of two interfaces (`Set`, `SortedSet`)? If the latter, then your Question is *not* a duplicate of the linked Question. Your title suggests the latter, but some more explanation is due.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difference is s have acccess to method shared by s type (if you don't cast it). But the object real type is the same.

Comment: You are correct, thank you. If I try s.first() for the first TreeSet, it will throw a compilation error: cannot find symbol method first(). Instead it compiles and runs just fine with the second TreeSet

Answer (score 0):

Calling `new HashSet<String>()` will always create an empty `HashSet`. While these are all different instances, they are equal, regardless of whether you assign them to a `HashSet`, a `Set` or even a plain old `Object`.

Note, however, that `HashSet` is **not** a `SortedSet`, and the second statement in the question will cause a compilation error.

Comment: Sorry, my bad about that. I edited them into TreeSets

Comment: All that I still want to know is if polymorphism is involved here in any way. with the acces restrictions regarding the interfaces methods

Answer (score -2):

Only their *apparent* type is different. Since their *real* type is the same, their behavior will be identical.

It's similar to:

```
Integer i = 42;
Object o = i;
String s1 = i.toString(); // "42"
String s2 = o.toString(); // "42"
```

Comment: Your code example is entirely irrelevant. The `toString` method generates a separate and distinct object unrelated to the original `Object` named `o`.

Comment: @BasilBourque It highlights that the behavior of `toString()` is the same whatever the _apparent_ type is. I just added a line to make it more explicit. Yeah, that's trivial, but IMO it answers to the question…